# XPages - using SSJS to access a dojo cookie variable - is this possible?

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

In one of my XPages, I would like to use SSJS or Expression Language (EL) to access a dojo cookie variable. Is this possible? The dojo cookie variable is set using dojo.cookie("sectionDisplay", "Allgemein", { expires: 1 }).

Comment: Check out; Cookie Management in XPages, http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cookie-management.html for Cookiehandling in XPage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this tip. I solved the problem using the following code: var request = facesContext.getExternalContect().getRequest();
var header = request.getHeader("Cookie");
@Middle(header,"sectionDisplay=",";")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved using the following:

```
var request = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();
var header = request.getHeader("Cookie");
@Middle(header,"sectionDisplay=",";")
```